# Des the django queryset annotation performs before slicing

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, performance

I basically wanted to know, the order of execution for Django queryset actions annotation and slicing.

Let `Books` is a model with around **1000** values in it.

```
some_books = Books.objects.annotate(
                  test_field=some-actions....
             ).filter(
                some-other-filters
          )[:100]
```

When I perform the above query, would the annotation of `test_field` will perform only for **100(sliced)** objects or it will perform for all the objects matching with filters and then do the slicing?

Comment: Perhaps it's same like with [order of annotation and filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) that annotation is executed based on when it was called. So slicing would be last thing to do